# How is data laid out in memory for a 3D cv::Mat containing multi-channel data?

Tags: opencv

I am trying to understand how 3D data stored in memory in a cv::Mat. I have a need to operate on the underlying memory directly. I am creating a cv::Mat as below:

```
int dims[3] = {4, 5, 6};
cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(3, dims, CV_8UC3);
```

I am accessing the first element using `mat.ptr()`. Is the data laid out in memory as

```
R0G0B0 R1G1B1 R2G2B2 ...
```

where R0 G0 B0 are the channels of (0, 0, 0) and R1 G1 B1 are all the channels if (0, 0, 1) and R2 G2 B2 are all the channels of (0, 0, 2) and so on?

Thanks for your help.

Dinesh

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html#tutorial_how_to_scan_images_storing

Comment: I understand for the 2D case. But I am more concerned about the N-D case i.e. are the channels always the fastest varying dimensions. Another way to put it is are all the channels at a specific location mat.at( std::vector<int>({i0, i1, i2, i3}) ) point to the first channel at that pixel. I would assume that would be the case given thats how 2D works but I just wanted to check.